# Rank and Invertibility Problem - Non Square Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathcal  M_{m×n}(F)$. Prove that if $\text{rank}(A) = m$, then there exists $B \in \mathcal M_{n×m}(F)$ such
that $AB = I_m$.

I think I need to prove that $A^{-1}$ exists, such that $B=A^{-1}$, but I thought that only square matrices are invertible. Is there another way of approaching this problem? Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, only square matrices are invertible.  Note that $AB = I_m$ does not mean that $BA = I_n$ (in fact, we can only have both occur when $m = n$).  Note also that we must have $m \leq n$ for this situation to occur.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to think about the problem: note that we necessarily have $m \leq n$ (why?).  When $m = n$, this is a simple question of matrix inversion.  When $m<n$, we may state that $A$ has some set of $m$ columns that are linearly independent.

Let $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_m$ be the (indices of the) columns of $A$ corresponding to a linearly independent set of columns (without repetition).  Let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector.
Noting that $A e_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$, we note that
$$
A\pmatrix{e_{i_1}&e_{i_2}&\cdots & e_{i_m}}
$$
Gives us an $m \times m$ matrix with full rank.  Since this is a square matrix with full rank, it is invertible.

Let $B$ be given by
$$
B = \pmatrix{e_{i_1}&e_{i_2}&\cdots & e_{i_m}} \left[ A\pmatrix{e_{i_1}&e_{i_2}&\cdots & e_{i_m}}\right]^{-1}
$$
Confirm that $AB = I_m$

Comment: I don't think you can say that $A_1$ is necessarily of full rank.  For example, think of a $m\times(2m)$ matrix for which the first $m$ columns are zero, and the second $m$ columns make up the identity matrix.  I think the best you can say is something like "without loss of generality, after permuting some of the columns of $A$, the first $m$-columns form an invertible matrix."

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith fair point

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is an $(mxn)$ matrix with $rank(A) = m$

then $n \ge m $ and the column space of $A$ spans all of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

So, $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^m, \exists x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $Ax = y$.

Choose $y_i$ to be the $i^{th}$ column of $I_m$. The the columns of $B (nxm)$ are the vectors $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $Ax_i = y_i$.